# Ionic Uncaught (in promise): invalid link

Tags: ionic3

I have probably a problem with `this.nav.push` in Ionic. I have done a login/registration page but when I login, I get this error message. I have to add some code in login.ts and e.g home.ts (which is the main page) ?

> Runtime Error 
>   Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: HomePage

---

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: HomePage
>       at d (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:3991)
>       at l (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:3244)
>       at Object.reject (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:2600)
>       at NavControllerBase._fireError (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:45465:16)
>       at NavControllerBase._failed (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:45453:14)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:45508:59
>       at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:11562)
>       at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:4622:37)
>       at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:11502)
>       at n.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:6468)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:3767
>       at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:12256)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:4613:37)
>       at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:12177)
>       at n.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7153)

@edit: The problem occurs when I want login to my app. Here is the code to login.

login.ts

```
public login() {
    this.showLoading()
    this.auth.login(this.registerCredentials).subscribe(allowed => {
      if (allowed) {        
       this.nav.push('HomePage');
      } else {
        this.showError("Access Denied");
      }
    },
      error => {
        this.showError(error);
      });
    }
```

---

auth-service.ts ( here is public function which executes my login and where I have password and email which I need to type in login )

```
  public login(credentials) {
    if (credentials.email === null || credentials.password === null) {
      return Observable.throw("Please insert credentials");
    } else {
      return Observable.create(observer => {
        // At this point make a request to your backend to make a real check!
        let access = (credentials.password === "pass" && credentials.email === "email");
        this.currentUser = new User('Simon', 'saimon@devdactic.com');
        observer.next(access);
        observer.complete();
      });
    }
  }
```

I don't know why this code is wrong. My home page in my app is home.ts and class is HomePage

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 23):

what you need to do is to add @IonicPage() before '@Component' and import 'IonicPage'  like this :
 `import {NavController, IonicPage} from 'ionic-angular';`

then you need to create a module for the homepage i.e in the home directory , create home.module.ts with the following contents

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from './home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
  ],
  exports: [
    HomePage
  ]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

and reload the project

Comment: I did all of your advices but still same error!

Answer (score 8):

The only problem in your code is when you write
`this.nav.push('HomePage');` remove the  **' '** quotes when calling any page, and write like this.

`this.nav.push(HomePage);` without quotes.

> Above answer is for ionic2, in ionic3 there is lazy loading where you
>   call like this `this.nav.push('HomePage');`

Comment: In ionic guide page there is no quotes.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Comment: its a lazy loading thing read here https://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/

Answer (score 3):

Turn out It work like a charm once you restart the server again, Took me hours to fix,If issue is not resolved by `@IonicPage()`, just restart your server. ie `ionic serve`.
Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just add @IonicPage() before @component in ts file for example:

**@IonicPage()**
@Component({
    selector: 'page-wall',
    templateUrl: 'wall.html',
})

Answer (score 0):

I copied login example. The error is similar.

Check points for HomePage :
(1) check whether home.module.ts is
(2) check @IonicPage() before '@Component' in home.ts
(2) remove HomePage from declaration/entryComponents in app.module.ts when facing open-error