# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: LoginPage

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

[image][image]I have started with ionic 3 (`"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.6"`) and getting this error. I checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969482/ionic-uncaught-in-promise-invalid-link) and many others but none of them is helpful in my case.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: LoginPage

`app.component.ts`:

```ts
const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => {
  if (!user) {
    this.rootPage = 'LoginPage';
    unsubscribe();
  } else { 
    this.rootPage = HomePage;
    unsubscribe();
  }
});
```

`login.ts`:

```ts
@IonicPage({
  name: 'login'
})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
    // ......
}
```

It worked initially but now it's not working and showing the same error.
Please let me know if I'm missing any other configurations.

EDIT: `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "my-places",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "1.0.16",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "firebase": "4.8.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.6",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "config": { 
    "ionic_source_map": "source-map" 
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `package.json` file?

Comment: @Sampath, I have added package.json file content in the question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using lazy-load, but you're also changing the name of the page:

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'login' // <---- here!
})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
    // ......
}
```

As you can see in **[the IonicPage docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/#changing-name)**:

> As mentioned previously, the name property will be set to the class
>   name if it isn't provided. Changing the name of the link is extremely
>   simple. To change the name used to link to the component, simply pass
>   it in the decorator like so:
>
> ```
> @IonicPage({
>   name: 'my-page'
> })
> ```
>
> This will create a link to the MyPage component using the name
>   'my-page'. Similar to the previous example, the page can be navigated
>   to by using the name:
>
> ```
> goToMyPage() {
>   // go to the MyPage component
>   this.navCtrl.push('my-page');
> }
> ```

So if you choose the `name` 'login' in the `@IonicPage` decorator, use the same name when trying to use that page: `this.rootPage = 'login';`

Comment: Glad to hear that @Gaurav :)

Comment: Is that mean can't we use like this then? `this.navCtrl.push('LoginPage');`

Comment: That's right @Sampath. By default, the name of the page is the same name of the class. But if you change it, you must use the new name and not the default name. `this.navCtrl.push('LoginPage');` won't work, but `this.navCtrl.push('login');` will.

Comment: Really nice info. Thanks for sharing with us +1 :)

Comment: please help me check..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49145729/error-error-uncaught-in-promise-invalid-link-sospoppage

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're using `Angularfire2`. So you can do it very easily like so,

*app.component.ts*

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
     this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
          this.rootPage = 'HomePage';
      } else {
          this.rootPage = 'LoginPage';
      }
    });
 }
```

Comment: It seems you're not using Lazy loading. So you need to do this `this.rootPage = LoginPage;`

Comment: While trying this, it throws this error: `Error: No component factory found for LoginPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`. I have added LoginPage in entryComponents section in LoginPageModule, is that correct ?

Comment: Are you using Lazy loading on your project or not?

Comment: Actually I'm not much aware about lazy loading, just started with ionic 3 and followed this article, `https://javebratt.com/ionic-firebase-authentication/`

Comment: Could you show your project structure using an image? i.e. `HomePage` and `LoginPage`

Comment: I have added image for the project structure.

Comment: It seems you need to recreate the `homepage`. It doesn't support Lazy loading if you used default project creation CLI. But  `LoginPage` uses Lazy loading according to your image. Use this `ionic generate page Home`

Comment: You don't need to declare `entryComponents` if you use lazy loading.

Comment: So this is my home.module.ts, `import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from './home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
  ],
  exports: [
    HomePage
  ],
})
export class HomePageModule {}`

Comment: This is constructor of app.component.ts :  `constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
          this.rootPage = 'HomePage';
      } else {
          this.rootPage = 'LoginPage';
      }
    });
  }`

Comment: Ok, it seems you don't have any issue there. Just restart the server and see it again.

Comment: Yes, i restarted it, still it shows the same error.

Comment: I have added another picture showing app.component.ts, login.module.ts and login.ts. This might help you finding if anything is missing.

Comment: You need to remove `HomePage` from the `app.module.ts`.

Comment: Yes, removing HomePage from app.module.ts worked alongwith the suggestion given by @sebaferreras in the other answer for this question.