# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: SosPopPage

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am coding a SOS page, when I click the button that I want it showing a popup page like this. Then user can choose phone number.

[image]

**sos.html page**

```
<button ion-button color="light" (click)="openSosPop()">Call</button>
```

**sos.ts page**

```
openSosPop() {
  this.openModal('SosPopPage');
  // let contactModal = this.modalCtrl.create(SosPopPage);
  // contactModal.present();
}

openModal(pageName) {
  this.modalCtrl.create(pageName, null, { cssClass: 'inset-modal' })
    .present();
}
```

**sos.css page**

```
ion-modal.inset-modal {
  // transparent black background overlay
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) !important;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  padding: 20vh 10vw;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like SosPopPage is not setup correctly.. Can you mention in which module you have set it and also add the page code?

Comment: @SurajRao  I import `SosPopPage` in app->app.module.ts file.

Comment: @SurajRao I follow other project did this one, and I am not using lazy loading but that project using lazy loading.. is it this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not using lazy loading

If you are *not using lazy loading*, it is not an [`IonicPage`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/).
Adding IonicPage decorator allows you to use string names to handle pages.

> This will automatically create a link to the MyPage component using the same name as the class, name: 'MyPage'. The page can now be navigated to by using this name.

Since you are not lazy loading, you cannot use a string to navigate or create modals and popups. You have to use the actual page/component.

Import the page.

```
import <path_to_page>;

  this.openModal(SosPopPage);//create the modal.
```